# gremlin shell hangs after opening a connection

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-zookeeper, titan, gremlin

my dev environment is Hadoop 2.6.0 HBase 0.98.10.1-hadoop2 titan 0.5.3

i tried to open a connection by

```
 conf = new BaseConfiguration();
 conf.setProperty("storage.backend","hbase");
 conf.setProperty("storage.hostname","127.0.0.1");
 conf.setProperty("storage.hbase.ext.hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort","2181")
 conf.setProperty("storage.hbase.table","smart_titan")
 g = TitanFactory.open(conf);
```

after that shell doesn't release the control,
i verified zookeeper logs, everything looks normal session establishment and all.

any pointers on this...!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured out the issue, by default titan establishes connection to znode /hbase

setting this property solved issue.

```
   conf.setProperty("storage.hbase.ext.zookeeper.znode.parent","/hbase-unsecure")
```